# Comic Book Identification (potentially Judge Dredd)

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a comic book I bought in the UK and read back around 2000 or just before. I believe it may have been Judge Dredd (2000 AD) or something similar, but it had more teen/adult themes.

The only scene I can remember is of a Jesus-like character cycling through a building. He then asks one of his servants to stop his bike. The servant then gets on his hands and knees, stopping the bike with his buttocks.

I know this is a long shot, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, my mind went all sorts of directions with what he stopped it with... I'm guessing that you're trying to imply that it got parked between the cheeks?

Comment: Correct! You can see how the scene has been in the back of my memory all this time!

Comment: I can't recall offhand if such events actually occurred in the book, but the style of humor described here reminds me of _Transmetropolitan_. Even if that's not correct, that series is worth checking out, as it's got a dystopian worldview and sense of absurd, sardonic humor similar to Judge Dredd, but certainly more adults-only.

Comment: Unfortunately not what I'm searching for, but it does looking interesting! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's the [Preacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Preacher_story_arcs#.22Proud_Americans.22_.28issues_18.E2.80.9326.29) comic.  The writer and artist (Garth Ennis and Steve Dillon) both also worked on 2000AD, which could make you think it was 2000AD, and one of the back-up artists was [Carlos Ezquerra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Ezquerra), the original Judge Dredd artist.  The 'Jesus-like character' is probable the decadent Jesus de Sade from the 'Hunters' arc. The issues featuring de Sade feature all manner of eccentricities and perversions, including 'interfering' with an armadillo and parking his bicycle in the buttocks of his servant, Dirk.

[image: DeSade parking]